# Azure api management not hitting azure redis cache when request have more than 10 MB

Tags: azure, redis, azure-api-management, azure-redis-cache, ibm-api-management

I have a problem because when I try to configure Azure Api managment with Azure Redis Cache my data does not always get saved, if the request "GET" is up to 9MB everything is okey the key and its value goes to the Redis cache but if the request exceeds 9/10MB the key is not written to the Redis cache.
I have checked that the problem is definitely on the side of the api management because if I write to the cache directly from the console application, all the data is written even for 50MB.

My policy in API management :
Inbound

```
  <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="true" must-revalidate="false" downstream-caching-type="public" caching-type="external" />
```

outbound

```
   <cache-store duration="1000" cache-response="true" />
```

If I change downstream-caching-type to none then request to 9MB not working only request max to 2MB

Comment: This mentions a max response size for the cache of 2MB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapi-management%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fapi-management%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#api-management-limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I change downstream-caching-type to none then request to 9MB not working only request max to 2MB

As commented by [silent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537195/silent), adding it as a community wiki answer to help community members who might face a similar issue.

As per [API Management limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapi-management%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fapi-management%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#api-management-limits), maximum cached response size is 2MB.

You can follow the [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices-development#large-request-or-response-size) on how to handle a larger response sizes:

- Optimize your application for a large number of small values, rather than a few large values.
- Increase the size of your VM to get higher bandwidth capabilities.
- Increase the number of connection objects your application uses.